# Disable hardware keys android rom

Tags: android, android-source, android-hardware

I want to disable the Home, Menu and Back button in my custom AOSP rom.
I´ve seached on the internet, and saw i can disable buttons after a succesfull build in the key layout files found in out/target/product/generic/system/usr/keylayout.
The file i´m editing is: Generic.kl
Now i´ve commented out these buttons:

- # key 139   MENU              WAKE_DROPPED
- # key 158   BACK              WAKE_DROPPED
- # key 172   HOME

Then i restarted the emulator, and the buttons still work...
Is there something i am missing?

Thanks, Stefan

Comment: why the close vote? The question seems to relate to the AOSP code itself, and is just as valid as any "I tried this code and xxx happened".

Comment: This question doesn't seem unreasonable. As for the question it self, did you try doing a make installclean before the second build?

Comment: Hi Andrew,

Yes i tried make installclean, but because the keylayout files are in the out folder, its generated after make.
So my modifications will be deleted.

Comment: Or am i doing something wrong?, if someone knows another solution to disable the hardware buttons i am happy to know =)

Comment: I honestly don't know but I do know you should not be editing files in out, you should edit the files that create out. I am very interested to find your results, I might start by looking at the .kcm and .kl files found in device?

Comment: I am also doing this but i m unable to save the file can you please tell me what sould i do

Answer (score 2):

here is a good place to look for editing the file PRIOR to compiling

http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/keymaps_keyboard_input.html

In the source you will find the default keymap under /device/vendor/product/ and it will be the file(s) ending in .kl

If you have a rooted device you can always edit the /system/usr/keylayout/qwerty.kl file on the actual device with a root file explorer.

I was looking for the answer myself and hopefully shared the correct information

*Edited*
Also I'm pretty sure unless you do some modding to the emulator before you run it the changes made do not persist after reboot

*Edited*
If you are looking to edit files on the device in the ROM before compiling try looking at the device.mk file for instance:

device/lge/hammerhead/gpio-keys.kl:system/usr/keylayout/gpio-keys.kl

this line from the make file for the nexus 5 indicates that system/usr/keylayout/gpio-keys.kl is derived from device/lge/hammerhead/gpio-keys.kl in the source code

Answer (score 0):

once you edit the 3 keys and add # to them in the keylayout 
do the same thing in /system/usr/keylayout/sec_touchkey.kl and VOLLA!! 
it works like a charm.. working perfectly on my galaxy s3.
once that is done.. download GES4 light control and turn off the lights on the keys too.