# disable hardware keys (home,back,....) in android 4.4

Tags: android, button, android-launcher, android-hardware

I am writing a launcher for kids, it has its own applications and folder and features. so when kids wants to play with parents device , parents run this launcher and they can be sure that their kids are not able to mess with their data. and to exit from this launcher ,parents should enter their password.
 so when kids are using this launcher the `Home button` and `Back button` also the other hardware keys should not work, cause for example if the `back button` works the kid can leave the launcher while to exit from this launcher parents should enter their password.

any idea that how can i disable `hardware keys` or any other way to handle it?

Comment: you should root your device to get an access to do that
please check that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22933041/disable-hardware-keys-android-rom

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable the Home, Menu and Back button.There is a way , 
find the key layout files found in out/target/product/generic/system/usr/keylayout. Open the Generic.kl file and make the below lines comments by adding a `#`

```
# key 158 BACK WAKE_DROPPED
# key 172 HOME
```

*Need any further advice , I am here to help:)
Referred from [Disable hardware keys android rom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22933041/disable-hardware-keys-android-rom)*

Comment: Thank you for help is this work after restart of device

Comment: brother I am unable to save the file

Answer (score 0):

you should override the onBackPressed method in your activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed () {
    your code
    super.onBackPressed();
    ...
}
```

for home button it's depends on which actionBar are u using. take a look at: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html