# how to prevent phone hard reboot in android

Tags: android, android-security, reboot, device-admin, rooted-device

We are working on a device guard application.
The main task is to save the phone from thieves by preventing them from  [hard rebooting/resetting](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/How+to+Hard+Restart+an+Android+Phone/107479) it.

This is what I have already tried, after a few days:

- Keep the screen off
- Dispatch random key events to confuse the key combinations coming from hardware:

```
ProcessBuilder("su -c input keyevent 26").start()
```

- Edit ***keylayout(/system/usr/keylayout/qwerty.kl)*** file to change the functionality of **Volume Down** key to break the combination. I couldn't manage to modify the file *due to Read-Only file system* exception even with rooted devices.

Device goes rebooted in any ways!

So, Is it possible to do so?

if yes,
How can I prevent the phone from hard reboot?

Comment: *We are working on a device guard application for rooted android devices.* sounds like a oxymoron to a certain degree. But beyond that, I would actually surprised if you can enable such functionality. Because *if* that would be possible, people could write a virus that like bricks your device, by blocking *any* input.

Comment: You're right. I've updated the question. I know it should not possible normally but a device admin is not a normal application. see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24474059/4799599